# Use ViewStub as generic layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

As I mentioned in the title, I would like to use ViewStub as a generic layout. What I mean is, currently I have my base activity class and base fragment class to be extended for other activities or fragments. So since I have generic classes, I wonder if I can have a generic layout.  Is it possible?

Example layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.Activity_Main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <ViewStub
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewStub"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Where `@+id/viewStub` content will change according to desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that programmatically by using the `setLayoutResource()` method to which you pass the desired layout id.

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.viewStub);
stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.some_layout);
View inflatedLayout = stub.inflate();
```

> When inflate() is invoked, the ViewStub is replaced by the inflated View and the inflated View is returned. This lets applications get a reference to the inflated View without executing an extra findViewById().

Here is the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html).